# Disqus API Cursor is Itself

Tags: disqus

I'm trying to get comments on a certain URL. I'm using PHP and when I execute my code I can only receive 100 comments. But when I try to get the other comments by using cursor it fails. I searched the reason for this problem and in json response I saw this :

```
[cursor] => stdClass Object
(
[prev] => 
[hasNext] => 1
[next] => 1435662645080280:0:0
[hasPrev] => 
[total] => 
[id] => 1435662645080280:0:0
[more] => 1
)
```

Cursor's next is actually itself. So even if I want to receive the other 100 comments I can't. Because I do not know what is the next cursor's ID. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

While the cursor id for next and id is the same, that doesn't indicate that you can't get the next page of results.  Cursor.id and Cursor.next seem to always be the same for my request as well.

However I check to see if cursor.hasNext and cursor.next is not empty. If they are not empty, I just send Cursor.next as the "cursor" parameter to get the next page of result.